# ORacle Forms Utility

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

Is their any utility through which we can determine the list of database objects an Oracle Form or Report uses or the list of Forms and Reports that use a specific database object.
For Oracle forms/Reports 10g

Comment: Your question was answered in OTN - https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10508427

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a tool made by Quest Software "SQL Impact" but it is not supported any more.

The easiest way to do this kind of analysis is to convert all your fmb/rdf to xml and then write a script in Ruby searching for db object names.

Alternatively you can use JDAPI to iterate over forms objects, but there is no JDAPI for reports. Using JDAPI is much easier using JRuby, you can find sample scripts there:

https://github.com/tomi44g/OracleFormsJruby